# Connecting Docker/buildx to preexisting builder in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, buildx

So I know how to create a new builder for `buildx` in a Kubernetes cluster before starting a build with `buildx` e.g. from outside:

```
docker buildx create --driver kubernetes --use
docker buildx build .
```

But could I also instruct `buildx` to connect a corresponding builder that was created indepenently? I've been looking for a configuration file where Docker/`buildx` might store  relevant information, but have not found it yet. I've tried this with Docker 20.10.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `docker buildx ls` to list the builders and `docker buildx use` to set the the current instance (or the default one with the `--default` flag). The config files for builders are located in `~/.docker/buildx/instances`, I believe, at least in Docker version 20.10.5.